# jQuery fullcalendar plugin in MVC3 page. Updating data in Ajax style

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, fullcalendar

I have

1. an editable fullcalendar grid with a few events,
2. hidden submit form.
3. hijaxed submit callback function
4. and ActionMethod that suppose to return some JsonResult.

The goal is - when user drags-n-drops an event from one day to other, form submits its data to the server, server checks validity of changed data and returns a result.

So basically fullcalendar provides eventDrop event, that I can use like that:

```
 eventDrop: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revertFunc) {
        $("form[action$='UpdateCalendar']").submit(); 
    }
```

and with snippet like this I can change the submit behavior:

```
  $(document).ready(function () 
  {
    $("form[action$='UpdateCalendar']").submit(function (){
     ...
      Here the data should be serialized and sent to the server. 
     ...
    });
    return false; // to override default form submitting behavior
   }
```

The questions is. How to obtain and serialize events array on fullcalendar grid, that was already rendered and displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use this to get the events from the calendar:

```
var events = $(calendarSelector).fullCalendar( 'clientEvents' );
```

The above will return all the events from the calendar.  You can provide a filter function as a second parameter as well.  See the documentation for `clientEvents` here [Fullcalendar documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/clientEvents/)

To serialize this events collection as json.  I would recommend the JSON2 library which you can find here: http://json.org/js.html